# c++ 2x2 array input line by line

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

```
cin >> m; cin >> n;

char grid[m][n];
cin >> grid[m][n];
```

I'd like to input char array line by line, like

abcde [enter]
fghij [enter]
.
.
.
and so one to get finally mxn matrix

how can I achieve that?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is what you need. Not this non-standard stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m, n;

    cin >> m; cin >> n;

    vector< vector<char> > grid(n, vector<char>(m,'0'));

    cout << "Reading "<< m << "x" << n  << " Matrix..." << endl;

    flush(cout);

    for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
    {       
        for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
        {
            grid[j][i] = getchar(); // TODO: Check if enter was pressed
        }
        cout << "Press Enter for next line";
        flush(cout);
        cin.ignore();
    }

    cout << "Result is:" << endl;

    for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
    {       
        for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
        {
            cout << grid[j][i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

I also prefer the string approach by Filip Kočica, but maybe this helps if you want a defined matrix of NxM size and then enter the values. Not sure if that is what you are looking for...

Comment: this is the one i'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"I'd like to input char array line by line"_ This is char by char

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) there is no need to use char arrays for this purposes.

You may use `std::string` in combination with `std::getline` and some container for storing these strings (`std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::queue`, ...). In your case i would prefer just `std::vector`.

Huge benefit of this solution is that its way more **easier** to work with and **less error-prone** than pure char arrays. STL containers allocate & free all their resources by them self ([RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)) and `string` **adapts** to size of entered data.

Here is simple demo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::vector<std::string> grid;

    // Read strings
    while(std::getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        // Store entered string to vector
        grid.push_back(str);
    }

    // Loop through container
    for (std::string& s : grid)
    {
        // Print strings
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way:

```
const int m = 5;
const int n = 4;

char grid[m][n];

for(int i(0); i < m; i++){
    cin.getline(grid[i], n);
    cin.sync();
}

for(int i(0); i < m; i++)
    cout << grid[i] << endl;
```

`cin.sync()` is important here to clear the input buffer.

- Also it is not safe because if the user enters a string that doesn't fit to the size of each line.